# Gson expected begin_object but was string...but the value changes type between responses

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, gson

So, i am trying to learn android by building an app in which i use the lastFm api to fetch similar songs. I use retrofit2 with Gson and rxJava.

To read the json response i use Pojo classes. To get the similar tracks first i have to search for it (first api call) and then i have to call the api based on the one chosen by the user.

Some of the POJO are common between these calls, so i don't have to duplicate them.

My problem is that in the first call the response contains an artist as a String (only the name), whereas in the second response the artist is an Object.

Obviously when i try to read from the first response Gson is expecting an "Artist" object but instead it gets a String. How can i implement both of them into one POJO, being the "Track"?

Here is my code i hope i was clear (i have a problem when i try to explain...,well, my problems)

```
public class Track implements Parcelable{

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("playcount")
@Expose
private Integer mPlaycount;
@SerializedName("artist")
@Expose
private Artist artist; // If i make this a String, the first call works
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("streamable")
@Expose
private Streamable streamable;
@SerializedName("listeners")
@Expose
private String listeners;
@SerializedName("match")
@Expose
private String match;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private List<Image> image = new ArrayList<>();
@SerializedName("mbid")
@Expose
private String mbid;
@Expose
private String mediumImage;
// Getters, setter, parcelable methods etc.
```

**JSon first response sample (not full response, only one result)**
Response is from the lastFm api

```
{
"results": {
    "opensearch:Query": {
        "#text": "",
        "role": "request",
        "startPage": "1"
    },
    "opensearch:totalResults": "1637",
    "opensearch:startIndex": "0",
    "opensearch:itemsPerPage": "30",
    "trackmatches": {
        "track": [
            {
                "name": "Ich tu dir weh",
                "artist": "Rammstein",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Rammstein/_/Ich+tu+dir+weh",
                "streamable": "FIXME",
                "listeners": "198819",
                "image": [
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                        "size": "small"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                        "size": "medium"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                        "size": "large"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                        "size": "extralarge"
                    }
                ],
                "mbid": "1752a3db-918e-43ba-b7ac-63bcc9a6433c"
            }
        ]
    },
    "@attr": {}
   }
}
```

**JSon second response sample (not full response, only one result)**
Response is from the lastFm api

```
{
"similartracks": {
    "track": [
        {
            "name": "Waidmanns Heil",
            "playcount": 1806826,
            "mbid": "e1e060e0-73e7-4939-ac80-635e8cba45a2",
            "match": 1,
            "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Rammstein/_/Waidmanns+Heil",
            "streamable": {
                "#text": "0",
                "fulltrack": "0"
            },
            "duration": 213,
            "artist": {
                "name": "Rammstein",
                "mbid": "b2d122f9-eadb-4930-a196-8f221eeb0c66",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Rammstein"
            },
            "image": [
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                    "size": "small"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                    "size": "medium"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                    "size": "large"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                    "size": "extralarge"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                    "size": "mega"
                },
                {
                    "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/1a82cbe48f604d4c8325122b09d310ed.png",
                    "size": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "@attr": {
        "artist": "Rammstein"
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your responses.
p.s. first question in stack overflow...yeeee!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inheritance** can be used here...

Make a common class for common objects - 
I'm taking my example - 
Say, there is one common value coming in every response - and that is `"status":"success"`

I'll make one Base class -

*BaseResponse.java*

```
public class BaseResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
}
```

We can extend this class where the status is needed to be parse - 
like

```
public class ResponseOne extends BaseResponse {

    @SerializedName("name_one")
    @Expose
    private String nameOne;
}

public class ResponseOne extends BaseResponse {

    @SerializedName("name_two")
    @Expose
    private String nameTwo;
}
```

Hope it make sense ;-)

Comment: So if i am getting this right. I'll keep my "Track" class without the artist and then make 2 classes that extend it, each having the correct type for the artist. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: Exactly. Create another POJO for data differences. Let the common fields stay in common class.

Comment: Nice i'll try that right now and if it works mark this as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it works, looking at the values. They get extracted correctly, although i have other problems to solve now so i don't see it on screen. I'll mark this as an answer cause it worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Similar tracks object is structurally different from the trackMatches object.

I would recommend making a second class object for the SimilarTrack response.

SimilarTrack would have an Artist Object and a Streamable Object

Where as TrackMatches has Artist as a String and Streamable as a String

Comment: Yes of course they are different. Sorry in my question i didn't make it clear that the problem is only in the "track" part of the response. I already have separate classes for "results and "similartrack".

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use polymorphism capabilities of GSON. [This tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson) might help.

Comment: Thanks i'll check this out!